# Why isn't my text inline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Not really sure why my register and login are right on top of each other. Probably a simple fix, but I'm pretty newish to this. I would also like to keep the dropdown menu to be right underneath the login text which is also having some issues. I just can't seem to get it to be like a normal dropmenu. A good example would of what I want to achieve would be the help box at the top of the stackoverflow site.  jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Karmatix/v2z5bnvh/ 
Also if you could explain the solution I would greatly appreciate it. I would like to learn why I'm wrong and understand the solution so it doesn't happen again. Thanks in advance!

html (got some jquery but that isn't the issue)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('li').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('ul>li').fadeToggle(400);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="text.css"
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Login
                <ul>
                    <li>1</li>
                    <li>2</li>
                    <li>3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Register</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
}

nav ul li{
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fdfdfd;
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fdfdfd;
}

nav ul li li {
    display: none;
    color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

Comment: That made the text inline however that screwed up the dropdown menu.

Comment: Check **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/evdrkd86/)** one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple reason as to why your list isn't inline is because you are calling `width:100%` on each list item. So there is no room for them to sit next to each other with each one taking up 100% of the width. But you also have a few structural issues in your CSS that could be corrected to help this example and future elements you may add to this nav bar.

1) You're trying to set all of your styles on the `li` tag (code below). For one you're using both `float:right` and `display:inline` which is not necessary. In your case you don't need to float your `li`s (***1**) (and I would use `inline-block` instead because `inline` doesn't take the width and height of its children (***2**)). Next you can remove the `background-color` (***3**) and `width` (***4**) so we can add them to a parent.

```
nav ul li{
   /*float: right;*/ //remove (*1)
   /*width: 50%;*/ //remove (*4)
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 30px;
   text-align: right;
   /*background-color: #000;*/ //remove (*3)
   color: #fdfdfd;
   display: inline-block; //changed (*2) 
}
```

2) Set up your `nav` container to have the color and width instead since it is the parent and could potentially hold other elements like a logo. Also add `overflow:hidden` which will be used to clear the float we're about to add to the unordered list:

```
nav{
   background-color: #000;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

3) Finally, to float the whole list container to the right, add the `float: right` property to the list's parent `ul` instead (***1**):

```
nav ul{
   float: right; //add (*1)
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   list-style:none;
}
```

Now your list will be inline and floating to the right like you wanted:

## [**EXAMPLE 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/v0k6tmgs/)

---

**DROPDOWN UPDATE**

In order to get the dropdown to work, you'll need to change a few more things:

1) The parent `ul` should be hidden, not the list item. So remove `display: none` from `li` :

```
nav ul li li {
   /*display: none;*/ //remove
   color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

2) Instead add it to the parent `ul` (**#1**). You also need to position this element so that it appears outside it's container. You can do this using `position:absolute`(***2**)

```
nav ul li ul {
   background: #000;
   position: absolute; //add (*2) 
   display: none; //add (*1)
   padding: 10px; //add other styling rules if needed
}
```

3) Positioning elements as `absolute` removes them from the flow of the document and makes them relative to the body if not otherwise specified. So to contain it from shifting to the furthest top/left corner you'll need `position: relative` to add to *it's* parent which is `nav ul li`:

```
nav ul li{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 30px;
   color: #fdfdfd;
   position: relative; //add
   cursor: pointer; //you can add this if you want - mouse pointer
}
```

4) Last, you'll need to correct something I had added above but now needs to change. That's `overflow: hidden` on `nav`. Originally I added it to clear the floated `ul` element, but (if it's not self-explanatory) what it does is hide the "overflow" (including an `absolute` positioned element "overflowing" it's boundaries). In this case the overflow needs to be shown because of the dropdown menu. So remove that (**1***) and use a clearfix instead (***2**):

```
nav{
   background-color: #000;
   width: 100%;
   /*overflow: hidden*/ //remove (*1)
}

nav:after{ //use ':after' to clear the elements (*2)
   content: "";
   display: block;
   clear:both;
}
```

5) **Bonus**: Also in your jQuery, to prevent an animation build up where it triggers the action over and over on hover you can add `.stop()` just before `fadeToggle()`:

```
$(this).find('ul').stop().fadeToggle(400);
```

## [**EXAMPLE 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/v0k6tmgs/1/)

Comment: When I do this my dropdown menu seems to have an issue (doesn't really drop). It just kinda appears to the right but barely. Any solutions?

Comment: @ArmandKarambasis Yes, can you explain who you would like your dropdown to appear? Do you want it to be the whole width of the screen like your example (which may not have been intentional due to the `width:100%`)? Or just a regular small menu under "login"

Comment: Just right underneath the login. A good example would be similar to the help button that stackoverflow has at the top.

Comment: Haha thank you. That really helped. Thanks for spending the time and helping me with this.

Comment: @ArmandKarambasis you got it. I added a bonus jQuery fix at the bottom of my post to prevent the menu from hiding and showing over and over if you hover in and out. As a comparison, hover over your original fiddle quickly in and out and then stop, you'll see the menu hide and show several times in a row: [http://jsfiddle.net/Karmatix/v2z5bnvh/](http://jsfiddle.net/Karmatix/v2z5bnvh/). Adding `.stop()` will fix that

Answer (score 2):

Your `li` tags have `width: 100%` on them, so they're taking up the full width of the page, then stacking. Setting them to `width: auto` (or removing the width, or setting it to a value) will fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You have set the width to the floated `li` elements to 100%, so naturally, they will be positioned on two lines, one above the other.

Perhaps you meant to use width of 50%, which would place the two `li` next to each other on single line.

```css
nav ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
}

nav ul li{
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fdfdfd;
    display: inline;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fdfdfd;
}

nav ul li li {
    display: none;
    color: #fdfdfd;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Login
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Register</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hmm that does make sense. Seems like my way of displaying the navbar on the entire screen is a bit flawed though.

Comment: Try adding more details to you original question to explain what you are trying to achieve.  This might lead to more inspired answers that will help you along in your design.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem: `width: 100%;`

As the `li` width is set to take up the full width of the page, it is forcing the next `li` below it.

Remove this line and it will work as expected.